# EditText and Button height issue

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-button

I've got a Button next to EditText control wrapped in LinearLayout. Everything seems to be fine except that the Button is significantly higher than the EditText and I'd like it to be the same height. The heights of @drawable/main_edittext and @drawable/main_edittext_button are the same, but even without background set, heights are different. In the application manifest file, application theme is set only to windowNoTitle=true.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/main_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        style="@style/MainEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/edit_message_button"
        style="@style/MainSearchButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />

</LinearLayout>

<style name="MainEditText">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/main_edittext</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#262626</item>
</style>

<style name="MainSearchButton">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/main_edittext_button</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff5500</item>
</style>
```

+main_edittext.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/edit_text">
    </item>
    <item 
        android:state_enabled="true" 
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/edit_text">
    </item>
    <item android:state_enabled="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/edit_text">
    </item>
</selector>
```

-main_edittext.xml

+main_edittext_button.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/edit_text_button">
    </item>
    <item
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/edit_text_button">
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/edit_text_button" />
</selector>
```

-main_edittext_button.xml

Comment: They have intrinsic padding on them dependant on the Android Platform version. See the source for verification: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res/values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to remove the padding and margins: `android:layout_margin="0dp"` and `android:padding="0dp"`

Also, per your comment, modify the `minHeight` to 0 as well: `android:minHeight="0dp"`

Comment: Thanks for the hint but it doesn't solve the problem completely. It seems that the Button control has minHeight set to some > 0 value. So, I also had to set minHeight to 0dp. I can't answer my own question, so maybe you could edit yours and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If the drawable of the button "edit_text_button" is a nine-patch drawable, try to remove or make the padding smaller.
And just in case, place different resources for different densities: ldpi, mdpi and hdpi.

Comment: Thanks, it is nine-patch but the problem was somewhere else. Check my comment to slybloty's answer.